# Why does Angular (1.x) allow a module's dependency to reference its components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following code:

```js
angular.module('app', ['app.core'])
    .factory('NameService', function() {
        return {
            getName: function() { return 'Omar' ;}
        };
    });
       

angular.module('app.core', [])
    .controller('MainController', function($scope, NameService) {
        $scope.name = NameService.getName();
    });
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        {{name}}
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

The result displays "Omar". Note, however, that the `NameService` is defined in the `app` module which is not a dependency of the `app.core` module. I understand depending on each other would be circular but why does this work?

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, every angular application has a [single `$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector).  When a dependency is registered, it's signature is added to the `$injector.modules` Array.  When a specific dependency is invoked, it's signature is retrieved from the array.  The `$injector` does not restrict access to the `modules` array based on where the registration originated from;  any registered dependency is available everywhere in the application.

Answer (score 2):

It's a design flaw in Angular 1.x. It works because Angular keeps a global registry of all services, controllers, factories, directives, and so on. "Installing" a module means putting all its contents into the global registry, using their name as a string key. So a module can still work if it does not register its dependencies, as long as some other module does.

This is actually a pretty common source of errors in large Angular applications, because you can end up using undeclared dependencies without knowing it, so reorganising your app's module structure will break things in nonobvious ways.

[Angular 2's module system](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) is better in this respect.